# installing exchange - running dcdiag problems

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, active-directory

Running dcdiag before installing exchange i get the following output:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   Home Server = SONATRIBE-DATA
   * Identified AD Forest.
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SONATRIBE-DATA
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host 43eb0641-57d3-4ab7-8117-c3eee2dbaa49._msdcs.sonatribe.local could not be resolved to an IP address.
         Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc.
         ......................... SONATRIBE-DATA failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SONATRIBE-DATA
      Skipping all tests, because server SONATRIBE-DATA is not responding to directory service requests.


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running partition tests on : sonatribe
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... sonatribe passed test CheckSDRefDom
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... sonatribe passed test CrossRefValidation

   Running enterprise tests on : sonatribe.local
      Starting test: LocatorCheck
         ......................... sonatribe.local passed test LocatorCheck
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... sonatribe.local passed test Intersite
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

How should my DNS be configured to satisfy this step?

this is a brand new instlal of server 2008, exchenge ina  new AD install.

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

43eb0641-57d3-4ab7-8117-c3eee2dbaa49._msdcs.sonatribe.local is a CNAME record that identifies the DC SONATRIBE-DATA. These CNAME records are used in AD replication. Check if the record is registered.  If your Windows 2008 DC uses itself to host DNS, there is likely a _msdcs.sonatribe.local zone. Use the DNS console to check if the record is visible.

You could also use nslookup if you are comfortable using that. Use nslookup against the DNS server configured on the DC's NIC and see if its registered. set type=all before querying the 43eb0641-57d3-4ab7-8117-c3eee2dbaa49._msdcs.sonatribe.local record in nslookup.

You should get an answer back when you query for record. If you don't check the DNS servers configured on NIC of the DC to see if they accept dynamic updates. Youmight also have some events in the system event log by netlogon complaining inability to register records.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your AD?  Your AD needs to be up before you can install Exchange.  The Exchange server needs to have a fixed IP and joined to domain.

regards
AL